# Get Model item in Xamarin on button clicked

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this listview in Xamarin:

```
            <ListView x:Name="LocationsListView"
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid Margin="10,10,10,10" Padding="5,5,5,5">
                                <StackLayout Grid.Column="0">
                                    <Label x:Name="lblAirport" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding AirportICAO}"  />
                                    <Button x:Name="btnConfirmFuel" IsVisible="{Binding AirportFuelSelected}" Clicked="BtnConfirmFuel_Clicked" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Grid>
</ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I want to get the item in the list which relates to the row where the button is clicked. 
Now I'm able to see the things I want to get through Clicked object sender parameter:

[image]

But when I'm trying to get the actual CommandParameter I don't get that as an option. What are my options, how can I detect from which item the button is clicked in the Xamarin Listview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just cast the sender and get its `CommandParameter`

```
var item = (Model)((Button)sender).CommandParameter;
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes that works. Is this good approach to achieve what I'm looking for or there is better approach? I saw some way with Command in viewmodel but I'm new in Xamarin and not sure how to use that approach.