# Send id dynamically on buttonImg click to delete from fire base xamarin form

Tags: firebase, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to delete a doc from firebase data base on click button Img but i don't know how can I send the id of the item into delete service

this is my view file :

```
 <ContentPage.Behaviors>
        <xct:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding Appearing}" EventName="Appearing" />
    </ContentPage.Behaviors>
    <StackLayout>
        <Grid HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
            <Image Source="https://bcckids.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Photo_Main_Slider2.png"                         
                   Scale="1.0" 
                Aspect="Fill"
                   
                />
        </Grid>
        <ListView
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Patients}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPatient, Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectionMode="Single">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto">
                            <Frame  Style="{StaticResource FrameStyle}"
                                        Margin="15,0,30,0"
                                        >
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  Margin="10,0,20,0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                    <Image Source="https://www.freeiconspng.com/thumbs/profile-icon-png/profile-icon-9.png" WidthRequest="70" HeightRequest="70"/>
                                    <BoxView 
                                    Color="Maroon"
                                    WidthRequest="1"
                                    Margin="5, 0, 10, 0" />
                                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding PatientName}"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start" Style="{StaticResource labelView}"/>
                                    <ImageButton Style="{StaticResource DeleteButton}"/>
                                </StackLayout>

                            </Frame>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource BlusButton}" Clicked="Button_Clicked_1" />

    </StackLayout>
```

and How can i wrote it in viewmodel and call thw service ?
this is my delete service :

```
public async Task DeletePatient(string ID)
{
    await firebaseClient
   .Child($"Specalists/406707265/Patients/{ID}")
   .DeleteAsync();
}
```

Comment: I assume `Patients` is `ObservableCollection<Patient>`. What you need is to get the Patient that corresponds to the list item clicked on.  See answers to [Get Model item in Xamarin on button clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57678589/get-model-item-in-xamarin-on-button-clicked). Note in question `Clicked="BtnConfirmFuel_Clicked" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"`. That goes in your `<ImageButton ...>`. Make a method in code behind file with an appropriate name, and put that name into Clicked. In that method, you'll do `var patient = (Patient)((ImageButton)sender).CommandParameter;`

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve can u please explain more :\ ?

Comment: and yes it's ObservableCollection<Patient>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code might look something like this:

```cs
// Your item model.
public class Patient
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string PatientName { get; set; }
}

// ... your viewmodel class
{
    public ObservableCollection<Patient> Patients { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Patient();
}

// YourView.xaml
...
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    ...
        <ImageButton Style="{StaticResource DeleteButton}" Clicked="ItemImageButton_Clicked" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>

// your view's code behind (.xaml.cs):
public partial class YourView ...
{
    private async void ItemImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var patient = (Patient)((ImageButton)sender).CommandParameter;
        await DeletePatient(patient.Id);
    }
```

In the `.._Clicked` method, `sender` is the `ImageButton` that was clicked on.
In xaml, `CommandParameter="{Binding .}"` passes the model item (`Patient`) to that method.

OR if DeletePatient is in YourViewModel, which is YourView's BindingContext:

```cs
// your view's code behind (.xaml.cs):
...
    private async void ItemImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var patient = (Patient)((ImageButton)sender).CommandParameter;
        var vm = (YourViewModel)BindingContext;
        await vm.DeletePatient(patient.Id);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much !! but i faced small problem when i run it and delete successfully i had this error: ` System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: list' ` 
 and pointing in this :         public ObservableCollection<Patient> Patients { get => _Patient; set => SetProperty(ref _Patient, value, nameof(Patients)); }

Comment: Sounds like you didn't set `_Patient` to some initial value. `private ... _Patient = new ...;` BTW, wouldn't `_Patients` be a better name for that private value? Its the list, right? ALSO, you can probably omit `, nameof(Patients)` from `SetProperty`. Every mvvm library I know of, automatically defaults to the name of the property you are in (`Patients`).

Comment: I did         `private ObservableCollection<Patient> _Patient = new ObservableCollection<Patient>();`

Comment: but this was last item in the list so it's become embty

Comment: But you got a null exception. An empty list isn't `null`, its an empty list. I don't see what you did that resulted in `null`. Start a new question, give as much information as you can. Give an example of the steps you did, that resulted in that exception. Include there a link to this question, so you don't have to repeat everything.